# JDBCSINK connector failing for CLOB field in oracle Database

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, ojdbc

When i try to insert a text in CLOB field in upsert mode, i get the message:

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

In insert mode it works.

confluent version - 5.5.x

JDBC Driver version - OJDBC8.jar

Oracle version - 12.2.0.1